# How to set the icon when invoking QQ share sdk?

Tags: sdk, icons, share

When integrating with QQShareSDK in my App, I am able to call the share function successfully, but in the target App, the look&feel of icon is default value, how to reset it?

Please see the snapshot as below: [image]

I want to change the logo at the bottom, beside the text 'QQSDKDemo2'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. First, You need to go to the [open qq](http://op.open.qq.com/) website.

- Login your account.
- Manager your mobile application
- Find the corresponding app
- Click The icon material

You just need to upload and update the icon material information

> Warning: Before you use the ID, you should update your app icon materials information. Because QQ Server have some caches.

I hope this answer will help you. Thanks!